# Is it valid to use a simple return to send back data from an AngularJS factory?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following two ways and they both seem to work:

```
angular.module('adminApp')
.factory('TestAccount', function ($http) {
    return {
        get: function (applicationId) {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/TestAccounts/GetSelect',
                params: { applicationId: applicationId }
            });
        }
    }
});

//angular.module('adminApp')
//.factory('TestAccount', function ($http) {
//    var TestAccount = {};
//    TestAccount.get = function (applicationId) {
//        return $http({
//            method: 'GET',
//            url: '/api/TestAccounts/GetSelect',
//            params: { applicationId: applicationId }
//        });
//    };
//    return TestAccount;
//});
```

The second method came from an answer to a question I asked on stackoverflow. The first way was some changes I made to it.

Can someone tell me which is the more conventional way and if there is any difference between these two. For me the first way seems a bit more clean but I am not sure if I am missing out on some functionality by using it.

I used the following to call the service in both cases:

```
    TestAccount.get(3).then(function (result) {
        $scope.testAccounts = result.data;
    }, function (result) {
        alert("Error: No data returned");  
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two approaches are equally valid.  I prefer the first variant.  No need to start with an empty object, set a property and return the object when you can just return an object with the property.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking the same and wondering why the other poster suggested the second approach. I thought I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Like Brian said, they're both equally valid.

The second way is more versatile. It lets you write a service that has multiple functions where some of those functions call other of those functions, in a way that is relatively easy to reason about.

Using that ability in a service defined entirely within a `.factory` method would probably be a bad idea, and you don't need it in this case anyway. But if you have one service for which you do need that versatility, it may be worth using that style for all services across the board.